# Is there a way to make ' ' mean \s* in Perl regular expressions?

Tags: regex, perl

This would greatly improve the readability of many regular expressions I write, and when I write a single literal space in my regexes I almost always mean `\s*` anyway. So, is there a "mode" in Perl regular expressions that enables this, like `/s` to make `.` match newlines, etc.? A cursory read through `perlre` didn't give anything, but maybe I missed something or maybe there's a different way to achieve this?

Edit: What I mean is, currently I write `qr/^\s*var\s+items\s*=\s*[\s*$/`, and I'd instead like to write `qr/^ var\s+items = [ $/` and have it mean the same thing using some means- and my question is whether such a means exists.

Comment: Could you give an example of what you want your regex to look like?

Comment: `$regex =~ s/ /\\s*/g;`

Comment: @mob I've added an example of what I mean, please tell me if this is not what you meant.

Comment: @tripleee I didn't know you could substitute within a `qr`-ed regex too, I might just do that!

Comment: Actually, this probably could be done with `qr` overloading.  See [Regexp::Grammars](https://metacpan.org/module/Regexp::Grammars) for a look at what's possible.  (It works by overloading the `qr` operator.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a sample of using an overload (http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Creating-Custom-RE-Engines) for your specific substitution.

myre.pm

```
package myre;
use overload;

sub import {
    overload::constant 'qr' => \&spacer;
}

sub spacer {
     my $re = shift;
     $re =~ s/ /qr{\s*}/ge;
     return $re;
}
1;
```

example.pl

```
use myre;
print "ok" if "this is\n\n a   test" =~ /this is a test/;
```

Comment: While I'm of two minds about the goal of my own question (since it violates the principle of least surprise, especially when /x is involved), this seems like the cleanest most DRY solution offered for cases where this is needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Nope, there is no such functionality available. But there is the `/x` mode that prevents literal space from matching anything at all, so that you can visually structure your regex.

```
qr/\A\s* var \s* items \s*=\s* \[ \s*\z/x
```

(except in character classes – `[ ]` matches a space again).

Comment: Thanks, I do (almost) always use `/x`, but was hoping to avoid this `\s*` mess at all. I'll add newlines and such and try to visually structure it better as you said, thanks.